# Who can see my Instagram Location?

Tags: instagram

Can someone see my location on Instagram, if I only like pictures of the person I am following, but haven't posted any pictures?

Is there any possible way that my location is sent out by Instagram?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://help.instagram.com/701414446593937) ?

Comment: @the_it_guy_you_don't_like What about on computers

Answer (score 4):

No, if you have not added your location in your profile and have not added any picture or video with location, no one can see your location.